# Swift: How to inherit from another ViewController? (Cocoapods)

Tags: ios, inheritance, cocoapods, viewcontroller

When using Cocoapods most installation guides instruct to install via Terminal (which is easy)

and then in Xcode to create a new ViewController inheriting from a certain file (which was installed via Cocoapods).

How do I do this?
Obviously creating a new file is fairly easy, but I don't understand how to inherit from another file?

Thanks

Comment: Swift or ObjectiveC?  The documentation on inheritance in both languages is [extensive](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID193) and easy to find.   Basic steps: 1) import your new library in your swift class, 2) declare your class, inheriting from whatever.

Comment: Swift in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do after importing the custom class is to SubClass your view controller.

You do this in Interface Builder by selecting the VC, going to Identity Inspector (Right panel) and selecting your SubClass in the Custom Class section, as depicted in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I understand what you mean and this was my first thought as well, but I cannot choose a different class, although the Pods are listet in the project navigator.

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the Workspace created by Cocoa Pods?  Perhaps you opened the Project by mistake?